# Word Adin that automatically update document on the server on button press on ribbon

Tags: c#, ms-office

I have a ASP.Net webforms Website , it has a document viewer i.e Viewer.aspx that shows MS Word documents, if some one wants to edit that document, there is a button for edit which downloads that document into MS Word format.

The user opens and edits the document on his PC after editing document again upload that document to viewer.aspx  which has an upload button. and the updated document is replaced with old document.

Now I have given a task that when some one download word document, he doesn't have to again upload that document. Instead there should be a Word Addin, that after editing when the user presses a button in that Addin, the document automatically uploads to the server and replace the old document.

Can any one guide me how can I do it?

Comment: I dont know from where to start ? any idea ? any clue ? any good tutorial and any good plan will be appreciated .

Answer (score 0):

why not host your document in Office 365, when they click edit, just open the document on line?

There would be no need to upload or download.

Comment: I am just a newly hired software engineer , I cant change the architect of the current application .